# how to draw polygons in OpenGL that have an outline drawn with a black pen and another fill color

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, draw, polygon

How can I draw a shape like this in OpenGL?

[image]
I mean, I know how to draw polygons in OpenGL. I want to know how to make the outline black and the fill color ( for example ) yellow?

Comment: Show what you have got so far. Can you render a simple polygon?

Answer (score 8):

You have 5 vertices.  Draw a `GL_POLYGON` with them and then then a `GL_LINE_LOOP`.

Note that `GL_POLYGON` is only valid for convex polygons.

Answer (score 2):

I would cheat. I would create the polygons in a 3d suite as meshes, and create different meshes for the borders. And then draw first the polygon and then the border, using the same transforms, with `glDepthFunc(GL_LEQUAL)`.
In this way you can also give the border a nice outfit: you could make them look as if they were drawn by a pen, or sketched with a pencil or whatever. Also, this solution is good to go with modern OpenGL, while using `GL_POLYGON` [is not](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/History_of_OpenGL#Deprecation_Model) .